# Unknown table 'hibernate_sequence' in field list

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have strange error here...

I have two databases configurated on this project, and when i try to save into local mysql repository, i get the title error.
In addition i have remote oracle db in use.

```
Hibernate: 
select
    hibernate_sequence.nextval 
from
    dual
```

and then

```
[nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown table 'hibernate_sequence' in field list
```

and there is no table named hibernate.sequence in database, or attribute in class.

```
   @Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;

@Column(name = "customerid")
private String customerid;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = C_Portfolio.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<C_Portfolio> portfolios;

@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDate date;

@Column(name = "date_time")
private LocalDateTime datetime;
```

Furthermore everything seems to be okey just before the save. When i check the class to be saved in debugger mode. it has all the needed values and everything seems to be okey.

Comment: Please share the version of hibernate and spring boot.

Comment: The fallback strategy for AUTO in Hibernate is SEQUENCE, but because MySQL doesn't support sequences, Hibernate simulates them using a table. Change your strategy to IDENTITY.  like GenerationType.IDENTITY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have simply used @GeneratedValue in the POJO, so it tries to find the sequence table. Since you haven't specified the sequence table name, it will look for default sequence table "hibernate_sequence".

For mysql it increments the value by specifying as like below in your POJO:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

If you use it, it will generate a table called hibernate_sequence to provide the next number for the ID sequence.

Comment: I just added that to all my Entities and it still looks for hibernate_sequence. i'll look for more entities but i dont know if i can find any more GeneratedValues

Comment: Try with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: Okey, there was one i didnt notice... thank you, that helped